# Google Firestore - Do small operations exist?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am evaluating different cloud databases for a new project. I have used Google Cloud Datastore in the past, but now Google seems to recommend I use the newer version called Firestore. In the past with Datastore I was able to do "small operations" which are defined as:

- Calls to allocate IDs.
- Keys-only queries. A keys-only query is counted as a single entity
  read for the query itself. The individual results are counted as
  small operations.
- Projection queries that do not use the distinct on clause. This type
  of query is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The
  individual results are counted as small operations

For example, if I had 1000 blog posts and I needed to only retrieve the title of each post, I could do a projection query at a cost of 1 read. With the newer Firestore I do not see this feature in the documentation. This would mean it would now cost me 1000 reads to do the same operation. Is this feature still there, or is it simply just not documentation? In the past I also used projection queries for things such as aggregation of votes, etc, so this a quite popular feature I would imagine among many applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such billing feature as "small operations" in Firestore.  For queries, a a document is either read or not.  You are charged for the number of documents read and returned to the client, with a minimum cost of 1.  There are no projections for mobile and web clients - either the entire document is read, or not at all.  There are projections for server SDKs, but they still cost an entire read.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Well that makes my decision much simpler, it seems then Firestore will be extremely expensive for me

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old at this point, but I think it is worth clarifying that you can still use Firestore ***in Datastore Mode*** and then it bills just like Datastore did in the past.

So you can still get the free small operations with firestore -- as long as you have set it up to be ***in Datastore Mode***.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#small_operations

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore